# Two web sites using EF, one of them has a SQL Server CE test database

Tags: web-config, sql-server-ce, solution, projects

I have a VS Solution, with two projects (of type "ASP.NET MVC 4").

One of them (`FirstProject`), in its `web.config`, has:

```
connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|MyDatabase.sdf"
```

**I want the other project (`SecondProject`) to be able to access that `.sdf`** (*the purpose is doing local tests, if you are wondering*).

How should the connection string look like in the second project?

I'm looking for something like

```
connectionString="Data Source=|SolutionDirectory|FirstProjectDirectory\App_Data\MyDatabase.sdf"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *share* the connection string, I would use just **full, absolute** paths in both projects, e.g.

```
Data Source=C:\Projects\MySolution\Data\MyDatabase.sdf
```

That works easily, from both projects - anything else will always be messy, kludgy, brittle.....

Comment: Hm I see.. But this solution is versioned (SVN), so every other developer would have to set this to their own.